gethostbyname_r is returning success even for invalid host name like 'abcd'
We were planning to use gethostbyname_r() to check whether the host is valid before doing sftp a file to the host. But gethostbyname_r() is returning 0 even for the host name 'abcd'.
std::string host = "abcd";
int rc, error_code;
struct hostent hostent, *hostentp;
char buf[512];

rc = gethostbyname_r(host.c_str(),
                          &hostent,
                          buf, sizeof(buf),
                          &hostentp,
                          &error_code);

if (rc) {
        std::cout << "Could not resolve host name : " << host << std::endl;
} else {
      std::cout << "Able to resolve host name : " << host << std::endl;
}

Can anyone please help me to understand why this is returning success even for invalid host name or if there is any issue with the code.

Please note that gethostbyname_r (and related functions) are deprecated. You shouldn't really use them in new code.

The most obvious thing to do in debugging this issue is to see what IP address it actually is returning.  What is it?  Then type that IP address with an http:// prefix into your browser.

As for your problem, perhaps your nameserver returns some kind of catch-all address in your local network? And if you're on your own system at home, some ISP's have been known to do something like that for invalid hostnames before.

Some network environments will return an IP address to a landing page. Like hotel and airport networks to get you to the registration page.
Easy thing to do is perform a name check to a deliberately impossible address like "QPWOEIRUTY.zzzjj" and see what IP address is returned.  If it does return an IP address, use that as hint that the machine is on a "captured" network. Subsequently filter out that IP address from all other calls.

Side note: New code should use getaddrinfo, not gethostbyname_r.

@selbie Not all hosts have a HTTP(s) endpoint.. HTTP availability is not realy relevant to whether or not you can do name lookup or connect to the host (for other purposes).

@JesperJuhl - You are correct. But the captured wifi networks like in hotels and airports use these DNS hacks to redirect the user to a landing page.
